# Terminal and console python --> diffrent results

Tags: python, terminal, console

I've got diffrent results from same code in python3 interpreter and terminal.
I'm runnin my code via terminal command
python3 "/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pulpit/aplikacja wag/moduł komunikacji serial/serial.py"
and im pasting the same program in interpreter.
It works in interpreter but not in terminal.

The code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import sys
print("Version ",sys.version)

print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
print("Version info.")
print (sys.version_info)
print("Sys.executable")
# Is it the same python interpreter?
import sys
print(sys.executable)

# Is it the same working directory?
import os
print(os.getcwd())

# Are there any discrepancies in sys.path?
# this is the list python searches, sequentially, for import locations
# some environment variables can fcuk with this list
print(sys.path)



import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        print("{}: {} [{}]".format(port, desc, hwid))

sleep(1)
```

The result in terminal by running python3 /full/file/path/serial.py:

```
    Version  3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 15:58:12) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
Python version
3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 15:58:12) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Sys.executable
/usr/local/bin/python3
/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pobrane/py3/Python-3.9.5
['/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pulpit/aplikacja wag/moduł komunikacji serial', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Version  3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 15:58:12) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
Python version
3.9.5 (default, May  4 2021, 15:58:12) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Sys.executable
/usr/local/bin/python3
/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pobrane/py3/Python-3.9.5
['/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pulpit/aplikacja wag/moduł komunikacji serial', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pulpit/aplikacja wag/moduł komunikacji serial/serial.py", line 25, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
  File "/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Pulpit/aplikacja wag/moduł komunikacji serial/serial.py", line 25, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial.tools'; 'serial' is not a package
```

And result from python3 interpreter when i run in terminal python3 command:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> #!/usr/local/bin/python3
... import sys
>>> print("Version ",sys.version)
Version  3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
>>> 
>>> print("Python version")
Python version
>>> print (sys.version)
3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
>>> print("Version info.")
Version info.
>>> print (sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> print("Sys.executable")
Sys.executable
>>> # Is it the same python interpreter?
... import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/local/bin/python3
>>> 
>>> # Is it the same working directory?
... import os
>>> print(os.getcwd())
/home/marcinanbarbarzynca
>>> 
>>> # Are there any discrepancies in sys.path?
... # this is the list python searches, sequentially, for import locations
... # some environment variables can fcuk with this list
... print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import serial.tools.list_ports
>>> ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
>>> 
>>> for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
...         print("{}: {} [{}]".format(port, desc, hwid))
... 
/dev/ttyS0: ttyS0 [PNP0501]
/dev/ttyUSB0: USB Serial [USB VID:PID=1A86:7523 LOCATION=5-2]
>>> sleep(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined
>>> sleep(1)
```

Even if the versions differs a bit it should run script from terminal and import modules normally, how to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't work because the `serial` module isn't on your `3.9` installation. To install it do `python3 -m pip install pyserial`

Comment: I'm curious how running `python3 script.py` runs 3.9 but just `python3` runs 3.6. Weird!

Comment: Yea, that confuses me too. I' downloaded the 3.9 version and make&install it so thats why it calls 3.9 version now. But still, I did it becouse of THAT errors with importing modules.
Ok. And now I cant use pip becouse ssl module in not available for my 3.9 python.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve got new ubuntu 64.
Python 3.9.4
I've done python3 -m pip install pyserial and it did install.

I'm still getting the same results.

When I paste code into interpeter I'm getting normal result.
When I'm tryin to run via terminal it cant import modules.

```
    Version  3.9.4 (default, Apr  4 2021, 19:38:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210401]
Python version
3.9.4 (default, Apr  4 2021, 19:38:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210401]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Sys.executable
/usr/bin/python3
/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Desktop/pytongi
['/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Desktop/pytongi', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Version  3.9.4 (default, Apr  4 2021, 19:38:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210401]
Python version
3.9.4 (default, Apr  4 2021, 19:38:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210401]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Sys.executable
/usr/bin/python3
/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Desktop/pytongi
['/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Desktop/pytongi', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Desktop/pytongi/serial.py", line 25, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
  File "/home/marcinanbarbarzynca/Desktop/pytongi/serial.py", line 25, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial.tools'; 'serial' is not a package
```

Answer (score 0):

ok. Now I can run my script by adding -I parameter.

It`s working as expected. What that -I parameter do in my case?